# How refactor 2 restcontrollers almost identical?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have 2 rest controllers which look the same:

File 1:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/foo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooAPI {
   private final ConfigService<Foo> service;

   @GetMapping 
   (...)
```

File 2:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/bar")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BarAPI {
   private final ConfigService<Bar> service;

   @GetMapping 
   (...)
```

Everything is the same, except the **private final ConfigService<(Foo|Bar)> service;**.

Is it possible to generalize a restcontroller class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create abstract class that you can inherit from.
So you get something like:

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractAPI {

    private final ConfigService<?> service;

    public AbstractAPI(ConfigService<?> service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping 
    (...)
```

File 1:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/foo")
public class FooAPI extends AbstractAPI {

    public FooAPI (ConfigService<?> service) {
        super(service);
    }

}
```

File 2:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/bar")
public class BarAPI extends AbstractAPI {

    public BarAPI (ConfigService<?> service) {
        super(service);
    }

}
```